# UIBezierPath Not Drawing

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, drawrect, uibezierpath

I'm trying to implement a method which draws a line based on gesture recognition but I can't get the UIBezierPath to display. I know the gesture recognizer is functioning because I print to log every time the method is activated. What is also confusing me is that the blue line that I draw previous to trying to draw the BezierPath displays but the BezierPath doesn't. Even if I manually add arbitrary points nothing is drawn, such as:

```
[myPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(50, 50)];
```

Here is the code in my UIView:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0, 0, 1.0, 1); 
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, 150);
CGContextAddLineToPoint( ctx, 480, 150);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

[myPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(50, 50)];
[myPath stroke];
}

- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) recognizers {

CGPoint translation = [recognizers translationInView:self];
NSLog(@"Logged");

[myPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(translation.x, translation.y)];
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why are you drawing some paths with CG and some with NSBezierPath? Where is `myPath` defined? Please include its definition so we can see what it's doing.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Sorry for leaving out the initializer. Within - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame I initialize as such:           
    `myPath=[[UIBezierPath alloc]init];  
    [myPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];`

Answer (score 0):

Where are you initializing myPath? Make sure that it is initialized.

And just like

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, 150);
```

, you need to call move to point on myPath before adding the line

```
[myPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0,150)];
[myPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(50, 50)];
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Sorry for leaving out the initializer. Within - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame I initialize and call moveToPoint as such:           
    `myPath=[[UIBezierPath alloc]init];  
    [myPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];`

Comment: @JShaev I tested out the code and it draws a line through arbitrary points just fine. Are you sure that initWithFrame: is called? Put a breakpoint and make an assertion on myPath in drawRect:.